# Genome sequence trimming pipeline on Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bioinformatics

I am looking to write a pipeline to automate sequence trimming for a collection of ~60 genomes. The programme code is:

```
trimmomatic PE -phred33 SA*_1.fastq SA*_2.fastq SA_*_forward_paired.fastq SA_*_forward_unpaired.fastq SA_*_reverse_paired.fastq SA_*_reverse_unpaired.fastq LEADING:5 TRAILING:5 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN:36 -threads 6
```

Where I would need the * to be replaced by a list of different letters or numbers which are listed in a csv file under one column. All of the * will be the same per operation but the operation will need to be looped through a list of different names for the different genomes and ended when the end of the list is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cut` and `xargs` as shown below. Replace `1` in `cut -f1` with your desired column number.

```
cut -f1 infile | xargs -n1 -I{} trimmomatic PE -phred33 SA{}_1.fastq SA{}_2.fastq SA_{}_forward_paired.fastq SA_{}_forward_unpaired.fastq SA_{}_reverse_paired.fastq SA_{}_reverse_unpaired.fastq LEADING:5 TRAILING:5 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN:36 -threads 6
```

Alternatively, you can use `system` command in a Perl one-liner like so (typically used for more complex commands, so `xargs` is the preferred method):

```
cut -f1 infile | perl -lne '$cmd = qq{trimmomatic PE -phred33 SA${_}_1.fastq SA${_}_2.fastq SA_${_}_forward_paired.fastq SA_${_}_forward_unpaired.fastq SA_${_}_reverse_paired.fastq SA_${_}_reverse_unpaired.fastq LEADING:5 TRAILING:5 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN:36 -threads 6}; print $cmd; system $cmd;'
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

**See also:**

- [`cut`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)
- [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html)
- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

If you prefer GNU utilities (`xargs`, etc) to the macOS versions of those, install them with `brew`:
[How to replace Mac OS X utilities with GNU core utilities?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your suggestion! I have tried this but for some reason the programme only runs successfully for the last row in the csv file and not the others. I've also noticed that although all the other output file names are correct, but the last one is SA_{}_reverse_unpaired.fastq i.e does not replace it with the corresponding number- could the error be because there can only be one file type with this name so it is avoiding running the other genomes? - ideas appreciated!

Comment: How does the output of `cut -f1 infile | xargs -n1 -I{} echo {}` look like?

Comment: This output looks correct and reflects the order that is in the file

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is, but this option may help: `xargs --verbose` (Print the command line on the standard error output before executing it.) If the macOS `xargs` does not have this option, you may want to install the GNU version.

Comment: I added another method using a simple Perl one-liner. HTH!

Comment: I have tried the new Perl command and it has fixed the previous error, however, only the last line is running still as I have realised the mistake is that when a new row is read from the csv file, it adds a space to the file name so the programme does not recognise it - is there a way to avoid a space being added after each row break in the csv file?

Comment: You can pipe the input before `xargs` or `perl` through this: `| perl -lpe 's{\s+$}{};'` to remove the trailing whitespace.

Comment: Apologies I'm quite new to terminal, do you mean to write the number sequence inside the code above (which would be completely doable) where would the sequence be written in```| perl -lpe 's{\s+$}{};'``` if for example the numbers were 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: No, I meant do this: `cut -f1 infile | perl -lpe 's{\s+$}{};' | perl -lne '$cmd = qq{trimmomatic...'` . This way, the strings used for filenames for `trimmomatic` do not have whitespace.